# Editing Default URL of SharePoint app tile on office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, applauncher

When I click on SharePoint app tile on main O365 page it takes me to `domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx` and not to the homepage of my SharePoint site.

How to modify this URL so that it points to the homepage I selected.

I know it has been asked before but I couldn't find a valid solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint tile and other OOTB tiles on O365 home page are controlled by Microsoft. We don't have the permissions to modify the tiles and its behavior as of now.

However you can add your own custom tiles to the app launcher that point to SharePoint sites, external sites, legacy apps, and more. The custom tile appears under the app launcher's All apps, but you can pin it to the Home apps and instruct your users to do the same (As it will not add this custom tile to home page automatically for all users).

**Reference**:

1. [Add custom tiles to the app launcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/customize-the-app-launcher).
2. [How to add a custom Tile to Office 365 App Launcher](https://sharepointmaven.com/add-custom-tile-office-365-app-launcher/).

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse.Is there any alternative?Can a custom site be added to main page?Not talking about app launcher talking about O365 main page

Comment: Here is a workaround suggested by Ehizo to changing the site logo and URL: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205942/i-need-help-changing-the-default-url-for-sharepoint-in-o365. I have not tried it. but if it is Ok with you then you can try it.

Comment: i have already checked that solution but unfortunately its not what i want.I also dont want it in App launcher because then i have to pin it manually for every user in my organization. Lets hope Microsoft let us modify such URL in future.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is what we have for now. and you are right that every user has to pin the custom tile manually.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.